# How to add an xUnit project to .NET 7 MAUI solution?

Tags: unit-testing, maui, .net-7.0, xunit.net

I want to run unit tests on my view models, services, etc. on my .NET 7 MAUI app. I following [this](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/adding-xunit-test-to-your-net-maui-project-ee36c00a8542), but it's for .NET 6 so I found [this](https://putridparrot.com/blog/unit-testing-your-maui-project/) which is for .NET 7 but it seems both use the same process. Anyway, I followed the steps after adding `net7.0` to my target framework, all my nuget packages get removed and when trying to build, I get these errors:

> error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:...project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

> error NU1201: Project is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Project does not support any target frameworks.

main project:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net7.0-android33.0</TargetFrameworks>
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net7.0'">Exe</OutputType>
```

xUnit project:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

It was suggested to unload/reload my project and restart Visual Studio which I tried but nothing has worked. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just in case, are you using the csproj root element `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, right? Also, do you have NET 7 installed and MAUI updated after installing NET 7, right?

Comment: Yes to all three. I also made a new solution, tried, and that built, but then I copied over a lot of my project into that and then the build failed. I couldn't get it working so I'm in the process of moving my viewmodels, models, services, helpers, etc. into a MAUI class library which seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found and presented by Gerald Versluis in his video

[Unit Testing .NET MAUI Apps with xUnit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9vIDLQwc7M)

Summary:

- On your MAUI project, add a core .Net target. My example is with .Net 8 but his is .Net 6, so this should work for any .Net core version. I am adding "net8.0" at the beginning:

Before

```
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

After

```
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

- Then we need, in the same project file, the output to be a Library in order to be consumed by the tests, but only when the target is the core framework.

Before

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

After

```
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>
```